# How to define methods for a type embedded in a struct that either implemented trait A or B?

Tags: rust, traits

I have two traits and a struct:

```
pub trait A {}

pub trait B {}

struct S<T> { a: T }
```

I can define a method for `S<T>` only when T implements trait `A` and `B`:

```
impl<T: A + B> S<T> {
    pub fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("do_something");
    }
}
```

How can I define methods for `S<T>` when T implements trait `A` **or** `B`? I tried to write two `impl` but it doesn't work:

```
impl<T: A> S<T> {
    pub fn do_something_else(&self) {
        println!("do_something_else");
    }
}

impl<T: B> S<T> {
    pub fn do_something_else(&self) {
        println!("do_something_else");
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
error[E0592]: duplicate definitions with name `do_something_else`
  --> src\main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     pub fn do_something_else(&self) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ duplicate definitions for `do_something_else`
...
20 |     pub fn do_something_else(&self) {
   |     ------------------------------- other definition for `do_something_else`
```

Comment: You'd ideally [need negative trait bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42721), something that is not in the language yet. Depending on your use case, you might be able to get away with using a [marker trait-based approach](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/38bvqw/specify_that_a_type_does_not_implement_a_trait/).